# Overlay text above image inside a loop in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

how can I loop a text over image inside a loop in react?
As of now, this is only I can achieve. Is there a way to position the text above the image?

[image]

This is just the snippet of my code

```
<div className="images">
  {/* looped over images to render */}
  {images.map((img, i) => (
    <>
      <img
        title={img.text}
        className="images__image"
        src={img.image}
        key={i}
        alt={img.text}
      />
      <p className="images__text">{img.text}</p>
    </>
  ))}
</div> 
 //scss
    .images {
    display: flex;
    justify-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    &__image {
        border-radius: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        min-width: 50%;
        min-height: 50%;
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not sure if I understand "above" correctly.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/imges-grid-y6ey9 May this help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `<p></p>` part appear above the `<img>` part, then you can enclose both in a div like this `<div> <img><p></p> </div>`, then add `position: abosolute` styling for `<p>` tag

Edit: I just tested this and found that paragraph `<p>` tag needs to be infront of `img` tag for this to work properly. i.e `<div> <p></p><img> </div>`

Comment: Remember to make div be position: relative :D

Comment: @dOshu I can't say i totally get about absolute property. Normally it is said 'An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>. However it never works like that for me, [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pfd406wg/) see this fiddle for example